# Firestore Transaction with conditional operations rolling back

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to run this following transaction in a flutter application.

```js
var db = Firestore.instance;
var chatReference = db
  .collection('Messages')
  .document(groupChatId)
  .collection("Chats")
  .document(docId);

var newChatReference = db
  .collection('NewMessages')
  .document(groupChatId);

Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {

  DocumentSnapshot snap;
  snap = await transaction.get(newChatReference);
  storedTS = snap.data['timestamp'];
  //'timestamp' is stored as string in the db
  //storedTS will be compared with a given string later on

  //update 'content' field (string) with new value       
  await transaction.update(
    chatReference, {
      'timestamp': DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString(),
      'content': 'My updated content',
    },
  ).then((val) {

    print('updated');
  }).catchError((e) {
    print('updateErr: $e');
  });

  if (storedTS == myCondition) {
    //if true then also update this other document. If not, just ignore it. 
    //During test if it IS true, both docs are updated as expected.
    // If it is NOT true, then the first update completes, since the console 
    shows
    //updated. But in the db the value remains the same, which means it was 
    //rolled back just after being updated (or so I guess).

    await transaction.update(
      newChatReference, {
        'timestamp': DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString(),
      }
    ).then((val) {

      print('newChat TS updated');
    }).catchError((e) {
      print('updateErr newChat TS: $e');
    });
  }
}).catchError((e) {
  print("rtError: $e");
});
```

I get a print in the console saying 'updated' but nothing changes in the db in the collection from the first update operation. If I take out the **if block** in the second update, then it works as expected. Flabbergasted! Hope someone here can point out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please edit the question to be more specific about what exactly you expect the transaction to do. We should be able to understand the before and after states of each document that should change.  I will also point out that you're not checking for errors from the call to `runTransaction` itself, which is important.

Comment: Ok, I added some comments to try to clarify some more. Also added .cactchError to the transaction, but it does not show any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after lots of digging around I learned that if you READ a doc in a tx, you MUST also do a WRITE on that doc. Beats me why it has to be like that, but for now we'll just have to live with it, I guess.